# converting classes to wcf services automatically

Tags: wcf, web-services, wrapper

I'm looking for a web service wrapper to convert my classes to web services. each class to a specific service and the type of instance management is "percall". are there any tools? Or are there any simple ways for this conversion?
for example this tool can add "service contract" attribute to classes and "operation contract" to public methods and also "data contract" to all inputs and output datas of public methods.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK that does not exist.

Web Services, with ASMX or WCF, are specific beasts. You cannot just take any class and make it a service. You need to define Data Contracts, Service Contract, an Operation Contract per method, etc.

Check out "Getting started with WCF" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 re needs to be thought through. However, given that DataContractSerializer will apply a reasonably sensible approach to a class not marked as DataContract, and given that you can define ServiceContracts and OperationContracts directly on a class (without service contract interfaces), I guess a solution such as a preprocessor which decorates all public classes and public methods in an assembly *could* be feasible. And .NET 4 / 4.5 are making endpoint configuration easier. But as you say, OP would be ill advised to do so.

Comment: Thanks. actually I need a tool to add service contract to a class and data contract to all input and output datas of public methods and "operation contract" to public methods automatically. I need this tool for a part of my master project. and I can't do it by writing code. because input project haven't specified.